# how to design datalist row have columns with different no.of rows

Tags: asp.net

```
ExamName       subject MaxMarks ObtainedMarks

               Hindi    100       88
AnualExam      English  100       76
               Maths    100       95
               Science  100       86 
----------------------------------------------
```

i want to design datalist control shown above i.e i want to bind examname and its related subjects in a single row.
Exam name in column with one row and subjects,marks of examname have to bind in related columns. but these must be in a single row as shown above.

Please help me

Thanks in advance
Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

you can use below datalist structure to accomplish your required layout.

First you need to bind Exam data with datalist . and on datalist ItemDataBound event you need to get dataset for repeater rptResults which can bind subject , max marks , obtain marks data against each Exam data.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlExamResult" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ExamName
                </td>
                <td>
                    subject
                </td>
                <td>
                    MaxMarks
                </td>
                <td>
                    ObtainedMarks
                </td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Exam Name
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptResults" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table  width="100%">
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Subject
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                MaxMarks
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                ObtainedMarks
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Hope this will helps you..happy coding....

Comment: can i use one dataset for binding ?

Comment: :can i use single data table to bind datalist and datarepeater inside datalist?

Comment: Yes you can use single datatable.

Comment: Thanks you for helping me, Prakash Patani

Comment: but  datarepeater  inside datalist can't not be binding

Comment: In datalist ItemDataBound event you need to find repeater control from item and bind against exam data.